# PHP WebSockets with Ratchet - example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, linux, websocket, ratchet

Here's some background first.

1. My aim is to use Ratchet WebSockets to create two-way client-server communication.
2. I have installed ratchet and accompanying software, as described [here](http://socketo.me/docs/install).
3. I have successfully created a Hello World application as described [here](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world).
4. Now I am trying to create Push functionality using [this](http://socketo.me/docs/push) tutorial. I have copied the code, modifying it slightly (modifications noted in code comments below), installed the ZMQ library (latest version, added it to php.ini, show up in `php -m` - in short, it's installed correctly). But the WebSockets don't work.

I will give my testing process with real live links to my domain below, so you can check it yourself.

1. My push server is exactly the same as the one in their tutorial, with the IP changed to my server's IP. I run this through SSH and it seems to connect correctly.
2. My Pusher class is in the MyApp namespace, same code and same relative location as in their tutorial.
3. My post.php is slightly modified because there's no need to bother with MySQL queries:

```
$entryData = array(        //hard-coded content of $entryData for simplicity
    'cat'     => "macka"
  , 'title'   => "naslov"
  , 'article' => "tekst"
  , 'when'    => time()
);

// This is our new stuff
$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
$socket->connect("tcp://light-speed-games.com:5555");       //my domain, still using port 5555 as in their example

$socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
```

This file is located [here](http://light-speed-games.com/apps/post.php).

4. My client.php is the same as theirs, except I had to add a little fix for IE to work with `when.js`. My problem is browser-independent and the same as it was before the fix was added.

```
<script>
    window.define = function(factory) {    //my addition
        try{ delete window.define; } catch(e){ window.define = void 0; } // IE
        window.when = factory();
    };
    window.define.amd = {};
</script>
<script src="/apps/scripts/when.js"></script> 
<script src="http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/autobahn.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn = new ab.Session(
        'ws://light-speed-games.com:8080' // The host (our Ratchet WebSocket server) to connect to
      , function() {            // Once the connection has been established
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        }
      , function() {            // When the connection is closed
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        }
      , {                       // Additional parameters, we're ignoring the WAMP sub-protocol for older browsers
            'skipSubprotocolCheck': true
        }
    );
</script>
```

This file is located [here](http://light-speed-games.com/apps/client.php).

In theory, what *should happen* is this (for example): I open `client.php` in Chrome with console switched on; then I open `post.php` in Firefox; Chrome's console should show the message 'New article published...' etc (from the `conn.subscribe` function in `client.php`). However, when I do this, nothing happens. The connection remains open (doesn't show the 'connection closed' error until I switch off `push-server.php` through SSH). The console remains empty.

I think that's all the relevant info from the last couple of days, a large portion of which I've spent on trying to figure this out. However, I've been unable to even make sure if the problem is with the code or with some server configuration setting I may be unaware of. So, I come to you hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

### Important edit

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the Autobahn.js method `conn.subscribe` not working properly. The connection is being established. When I change the code to:

```
function() {            // Once the connection has been established
            console.log('Connection established');
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        }
```

Then `Connection established` is shown in the console correctly. So I believe we need to troubleshoot the subscribe method. If someone can explain to me how it works, and what exactly "topic" and "data" are supposed to be, it would be of great help. The Autobahn documentation uses a URL as an argument for this method (see [here](http://autobahn.ws/js/tutorials/pubsub/)).

Comment: I wonder if this should be closed as not reproducible, if the solution was that the port is not open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it correct to see your host light-speed-games.com on port 8080 is not functioning? If not, I would suggest to fix this as it is likely its causing your issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I missed your answer somehow. Are you saying I should check with my hosting provider about this port not working?

Comment: Perform a telnet from your computer to host light-speed-games.com on port 8080. You probably will see the same result as me ( the connection will not establish ). I do not know the reason nor do I know you should contact your hosting company to have this sorted out ( although i guess you should:) ). Because the connection will not establish on this 'low-level' test, i do understand why your javascript also does not perform its logic -> its not getting connected.

Comment: That makes sense - I will try this later today and let you know. I'm sorry the bounty expired as I was away for New Year's but I can at least award half the bounty amount if this works.

Comment: You're right, the port is closed for TCP connections. I tried opening it with `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --syn -j ACCEPT`, followed by `service iptables save` and restarting Apache, but it seems it's still closed. Any ideas?

Comment: Btw, I get the same for port 5555. Standard ports like 21 and 22 are functioning fine though.

Comment: Does the port 8080 open when you telnet it with localhost from the server itself? If not, it is likely the apache server is not bound to 8080. If it does open, it is possible your hosting provider needs to make an extra firewall rule to allow port 8080 for inbound connections.

Comment: I had the hosting people open port 8080, but nothing has changed, still the same issue. I'm sorry, but how do I telnet "from the server itself"? I tried using the `telnet` command through SSH as root, but it said `command not found`.

Comment: That means you don't have the telnet client installed on your host. Install it with either your package manager (like 'yum install telnet' or 'apt-get install telnet' or something like that, it depends on your OS/package manager ). When installed, you can run the command
    telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
127.0.0.1 is your loopback ip and it should work, if for any reason your apache service is specifically listening on an exact ip ( like your external ip or natted internal ip, use that ip instead ).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I installed telnet and tried it. It worked on some ports I know are open, like port 21. However, it said 'connection refused' on port 8080. In both cases, I used `telnet localhost port#`. What can I do now to resolve this?

Comment: I suggest to start a question with this issue, your webserver is not listening on port 8080 and this can be caused by numerous things like a faulty httpd.conf or anything apache related.

Comment: I think I'll try to dump it on the hosting people, if they refuse to help I'll start a new question. Maybe Server Fault is a more natural environment for this question than Stack overflow, then? Either way, I'll select your answer as the correct one since you were on the right trail.

Answer (score 7):

Your client is looking for an article in `kittensCategory`, but you are sending category `macka`. Try this:

```
$entryData = array(
    'cat'     => "kittensCategory",
    'title'   => "naslov",
    'article' => "tekst",
    'when'    => time()
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out in the morning (not home now). This is a bit weird to me, I don't think I understand it. I thought "kittensCategory" was just an array item, where 'cat' was the key and 'kittensCategory' is the value. It then references `data.title` - will that print our "naslov" as expected?

Comment: It still doesn't work after changing "macka" to "kittensCategory". Could you explain to me the whole `conn.subscribe` function. I don't get it. What are `topic` and `data` in this case?

Comment: Also, I've edited my question with some new information, partly based on what you pointed out and partly on some research I just did.